# The page will closed & saved after a few minutes

Tags: asp.net, security

My application is in **Asp.net** coded **C#**.

**My requirement :**

- If someone has opened his page and didn't do nothing, then after 5 minutes the page will be closed and the changes will saved. 
  (this feature is exists in bank pages or another pages with protection)

**Suggest how can i achieve the needed result.**

Comment: Don't.  You have no idea how annoying that is.

Comment: Saving data (providing you don't overwrite the original) is ok. Closing a webpage without user consent isn't. And I think my browser won't even allow javascript to do that.

Comment: It is annoying but there are valid reasons for having a page automatically logging you off. I am thinking of applications where you're viewing sensitive or confidential info.

Comment: this feature is exist in a banks pages or another pages with protection

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some client-side scripting to accomplish this. In your script you will need to use: setTimeout to set a timer to go off after 5 minutes of inactivity. (The timer should get reset whenever the user is actively doing something). When the timer goes off, call a function to postback to do a "save and exit".

Like @CodeOfChaos says Javascript might not let you close the browser. In my opinion it would be better to redirect the inactive user to a page telling them "Your changes have been automatically saved and you have been logged out."

Comment: O.K. so how can i do that ( set a timer and reset whenever the user is actively doing something)?